# Coredata on iphone: I can delete data only if I restart the application

Tags: iphone, core-data

I've a simple applications that lets you create groups of people form persons in your AddressBook... So Groups and Persons are in a one-to-many relationships, since a Group can have multiple persons. That's not a many-to-many since I create my own model of Person.

Adding data works without problems.

Deleting data doesn't. If I create a new Person, I must restart the app to delete it or the to delete the Group that Person belongs. Otherwise I get a "EXC BAD ACCESS" in the console. With NSZombieEnabled in the enviroment I get `-[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x75140d0`.

I start with the CoreData stuff automatically created by XCode, create the RootViewController (subclass of TableViewController), I pass it the context and put it in a NavigationController.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

//Creo il controller root e gli passo il context
RootViewController *rvc = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
rvc.context = [self managedObjectContext];

//Creo il navcon, gli associo il root e lo rendo visibile
navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rvc];
[window addSubview:navCon.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];

[rvc release];
return YES;
```

}

The RootViewController shows the Groups, then clicking on a row lets you modify persons in that group, passing the "nuovogruppo" (the Group Model associated with that row)

```
- (void)showPersoneControllerWithGruppo:(Gruppo *)nuovogruppo {

PersoneController *pc = [[PersoneController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
pc.gruppo = nuovogruppo;
pc.context = self.context;
pc.delegate = self;
//NSLog(@"%@",[gruppi objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pc animated:YES];
[pc release];
```

}

And this is how I delete the person (`gruppo` is the Group model these persons belong to, `persone` is an array filled with these persons on viewDidLoad, removeGPObject is an accessor method generated by XCode (Group to Persons relationship))

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [gruppo removeGPObject:[persone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [persone removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
}
```

}

I hope someone can help me...

**UPDATE**

Since I was having errors about messages sent to already released instances I tried commenting out all the [... release] lines and finally find out what was causing the problem. The problem was in the creation method of the record and not in the deleting method. Here is the method I use to create it. 
The line that was causing the roblem is `[NomeCognome release]`
I'd be very grateful if someone could explain me why this line crashes the app.

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier {

if (property == kABPersonPhoneProperty) {
    ABMultiValueRef phoneProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person,property);
    NSString *phone = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneProperty,identifier);
    NSString *firstName = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
    NSString *surname = (NSString *)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);
    NSString *NomeCognome = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, surname];
    [firstName release];
    [surname release];

    Persona *persona = (Persona *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Persona" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    persona.ABRR = phone;
    persona.NomeCognome = NomeCognome;
    [phone release];
    [NomeCognome release]; //This line makes the app crash!!! Why???

    [gruppo addGPObject:persona];

    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    [self.delegate PersoneControllerDidSave:self];
    [self loadContentAndReload:YES];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Why that line crashes the app?

Comment: make sure you are not releasing your CoreData object in your dealloc method. If not add a global breakpoint for objc_exception_throw to check where in the stack the message to a released object is being sent from.

Comment: I've updated my question, please take a look again... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `reloadData` method at the end as the following.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    [gruppo removeGPObject:[persone objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    [persone removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    NSError *error;
    [context save:&error];
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

It may work now.